Pyspark: Subset Array based on other column value
I use Pyspark in Azure Databricks to transform data before sending it to a sink. In this sink any array must at most have a length of 100. In my data I have an array that is always length 300 an a field specifying how many values of these are relevant (n_relevant).
n_relevant values might be:

below 100 -> then I want to keep all values
between 100 and 300 -> then I want to subsample based on modulo
above 300 -> then I want to subsample modulo 3

E.g.:
array: [1,2,3,4,5,...300]
n_relevant: 4
desired outcome: [1,2,3,4]

array: [1,2,3,4,5,...300]
n_relevant: 200
desired outcome: [1,3,5,...199]

array: [1,2,3,4,5,...300]
n_relevant: 300
desired outcome: [1,4,7,...298]

array: [1,2,3,4,5,...300]
n_relevant: 800
desired outcome: [1,4,7,...298]

This little program reflects the desired behavior:
from math import ceil

def subsample(array:list,n_relevant:int)->list:
    if n_relevant<100:
        return [x for i,x in enumerate(array) if i<n_relevant]
    if 100<=n_relevant<300:
        mod=ceil(n_relevant/100)
        return [x for i,x in enumerate(array) if i%mod==0 and i<n_relevant]
    else:
        return [x for i,x in enumerate(array) if i%3==0]
        
n_relevant=<choose n>

t1=[i for i in range(300)]

subsample(t1,n_relevant)

What I have tried:
transforms to set undesired values to 0 and remove those with array_remove could subset with a specific modulo BUT cannot adopt to n_relevant. Specifically you cannot hand a parameter to the lambda function and you cannot dynamically change the function.

Can you share what is your expected output?

Basically what you can see in the question where I have example inputs would be the input-output relation.

You can filter by index as follows
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, IntegerType, ArrayType

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [[list(range(300)), 4], [list(range(300)), 200], [list(range(300)), 300], [list(range(300)), 800]],
    schema=StructType(
        [
            StructField("array", ArrayType(IntegerType())),
            StructField("n_relevant", IntegerType()),
        ]
    ),
)

df = df.withColumn(
    "result",
    F.when(F.col("n_relevant") <= 100, F.slice("array", 1, F.col("n_relevant")))
    .when(
        F.col("n_relevant") <= 200,
        F.filter(
            F.slice("array", 1, F.col("n_relevant")), lambda _, index: index % 2 == 0
        ),
    )
    .otherwise(
        F.filter(
            F.slice("array", 1, F.col("n_relevant")), lambda elem, index: index % 3 == 0
        )
    ),
)
display(df)


You can try sequence function to create the array indices (check the 3rd argument step) and then apply transform function, see below SQL:
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("subsample", F.expr("""
    transform(sequence(1,300,if(n_relevant<100,1,IF(n_relevant<300,ceil(n_relevant/100),3))), i -> arr_column[i-1])
"""))

Below using API functions:
df.withColumn("subsample", 
  F.transform(
      F.sequence(
          F.lit(1)
        , F.lit(300)
        , F.when(F.col('n_relevant')<100,1).when(F.col('n_relevant')<300,F.ceil(F.col("n_relevant")/100)).otherwise(3)
      )
    , lambda i: F.col("arr_column")[i-1]
  )
)

correction: the array index was 1-off in the original post.
